# How to use layout Properties > SummaryType to Sum a columns values

Tags: acumatica

How do I configure **Layout Properties > Footer** to show at the bottom of a transactions grid.

I want to show the text "Totals:" below the Inventory ID column, and a
Sum of the Quantity below the Quantity column.

I have set a Text layout property on the Inventory ID column:
[Layout Properties > Footer > Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbFyN.png)

and a SummaryType layout property on the Quantity column:
[Layout Properties > Footer > SummaryType: Sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEXl5.png)

after publishing, no additional footer appears below the transactions grid (expected to appear between the horizontal scroll bar and availability info:
[Sales Order Transactions Grid missing footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGs1.png)